# C++ writing to file error in Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I have been trying to learn C++ recently, but I have stumbled across some errors. For example, when I try to run this code to ask the user what they want outputted to a file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

    main() {
        string output; //Declare variables before starting
        FILE * file = fopen("newfile.txt","w"); //creates file
        cout << "Entire something that you want to be written to the file: " << endl;
        cin.getline(output, 256);  //Asks what you want to put into file
        fprintf(file, output); //Puts output into file
        fclose(file);   //closes file
        return 0;
    }
```

using

```
g++ -o main test.cpp
```

I get this error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:10:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::getline(std::string&, int)’
  cin.getline(output, 256);
                         ^
test.cpp:10:25: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:40:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:618:5: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type*, std::streamsize, std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type = char; std::streamsize = long int]
     basic_istream<char>::
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:618:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:427:7: note: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type*, std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::char_type = char; std::streamsize = long int]
       getline(char_type* __s, streamsize __n)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/istream:427:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘std::basic_istream<char>::char_type* {aka char*}’
test.cpp:11:22: error: cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int fprintf(FILE*, const char*, ...)’
  fprintf(file, output);
                      ^
```

Could someone please help me? And please forgive me if this is something that can be easily solved, I am fairly new to C++ and do not quite understand it yet.

Comment: You should have written [`getline(cin,output);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: and included `<string>`

Answer (score 1):

The header for [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/) is missing:

```
#include <string>
```

Without it, sring isn't defined, and everywhere you use output, you'll have errors

With the include you'll have a lot less errors.  But this line has another issue (as  πάντα ῥεῖ already pointed out):

```
cin.getline(output, 256);
```

because [`cin.getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) expects a `char*` and the length.  If you want to use a string,  you have to use the function [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), without size (limited to strings maximume size) and on an istream:

```
 getline(cin, output);
```

***Last remark:***  you are of course free to mix c-style io and streams.  But you could win from getting used to [streams for all your file io](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/).

Comment: Also [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) doesn't provide a signature that takes a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs at the line

```
cin.getline(output, 256);
```

According to the documentation for [std::istream::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/), the first argument for `cin.getline()` should be a `char *` and not a `std::string` as you have declared it.

Try changing the declaration of output to a `char *` like so

```
char[256] output;
```

**Edit:** Using `std::getline` as the others have said would be a better idea though.

Comment: _"Try changing the declaration of output to a `char *` like so"_ That's not so good advice IMHO.

Comment: Fixed sized buffers are just a bad idea all around.  What's so magic about 256, and what about buffer overruns?  Note the existence of [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Beacuse OP already uses `std::string` which is the better choice over `char*` and managing memory by hand, or having a fixed size buffer. He can just juse `std::getline()` instead, which takes a `std::string`.

Comment: @HostileFork True, but it would seem that he is following a tutorial which is why he used `cin.getline(output, 256)`, that's why I used 256 too. I would agree `std::getline` would be a better choice too though.